Infinite Fibonacci word generation
I was reading about the Fibonacci sequence and stumbled upon the Fibonacci word. It looks pretty straight forward, but one thing I do not understand. Probably something trivial.
According to Wikipedia and Encyclopedia of Mathematics you start with $f_1$ and $f_2$ and generate the $n$-th finite word $f_{n}$ by concatenation of $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n-2}$. For example with $f_1=a$ and $f_2= ab$ we get:
$f_3 = aba \\
f_4 = abaab \\
...$
Now, the Fibonacci word $F$ is defined as
$F = f_1 \cdot f_2 \cdot f_3 \cdot f_4 \cdot \;...$
so if I am not mistaken, just a concatenation of all $f_i$.
In this example it would be:
$F = aababaabaab...$
However, according to the source mentioned above, it should be:
$F = aabaababaab...$
What am I missing here?

Well, no. f3 = f1f2 (the way you have it, f1 comes first) and f4 = f3f2 = (f1f2)f2 = f1f2f2, so each fi appears twice in the expansion (except f1).

@BarryCarter so f3 would be aab? Because that would be different from the definition in Wikipedia...

I was wrong, sorry. You are correct in saying f3=f2f1. However, my point holds: since f4=f3f2, we substitute for f3 to get f4=f2f1f2, and, again, we see that f2 appears twice. So, it's not a simple concatenation: each fi (except f1) appears twice
